# How to mock a dependency's response when unit-testing in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-unittest

I am trying to write unit test for some of Python classes I have created. I have created a class for wrapping s3 functionalities, and in that class I'm initializing boto3 s3 client.

```
class S3_Client:

    def __init__(self, bucket_name):
        self.s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=e_config["aws_access_key"], aws_secret_access_key=e_config["aws_secret_key"])
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name

    def fetch(self, key):
        response = self.s3.get_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=key)

        return self.__prepare_file_info(response, key) # return formatted response
```

I would like to test method fetch with mocked response from self.s3.get_object. This is my test class:

```
import unittest
from .aws_s3_service import S3_Client # class I want to test
import boto3
from botocore.stub import Stubber

class TestS3_Client(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = boto3.client('s3')
        self.stubber = Stubber(self.client)

    def test_fetch(self):
        get_object_response = {...} # hardcoded response
        self.stubber.add_response('get_object', get_object_response, {"Bucket": "test_bucket", "Key": "path/to/file/test_file.txt"})

        with self.stubber:
            client = S3_Client("test_bucket")
            result = client.fetch("path/to/file/test_file.txt")
```

The stubber is not actually injected into S3_Client, a real call to S3 is made. How do I inject the stubber? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're requesting with a newly created `S3_Client("test_bucket")` not the stubbed `self.client`. You gotta stub the client which the library code actually uses.

Comment: @wim yes I got that, but how do I actually pull that off?

Comment: Usually patching with `mock`. Or a higher-level test double which does the monkeypatch for you, such as [`moto`](https://github.com/spulec/moto).

Answer (score -1):

You need to make `S3_Client` accept a client object in a constructor argument.
In this way in your tests you can create a client, stub it, then inject it to `S3_Client` as a parameter.

If you don't like having to always create that client outside of the class, you can make it an optional argument, and create an instance in `__init__` if none was passed:

```py
class S3_Client:
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, s3=None):
        if s3 is None:
            self.s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=e_config["aws_access_key"],                 aws_secret_access_key=e_config["aws_secret_key"])
        else:
            self.s3 = s3
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
    ...
```

In the code of your test you would then say: `client = S3_Client("test_bucket", self.client)`.

Comment: Then how would you get test coverage into the `if s3 is None:` branch of the conditional? If tests always pass in a client explicitly, then this part of the code would never get reached in test. Even worse - the code under test is not the same code which actually runs in prod. It would be more typical to just mock/patch out `boto3.client`, or use a higher-level library such as [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) which injects a fake.

Comment: If you care about coverage so much then you can just ignore the second part of my answer where I was just suggesting a shortcut. Creating the client object inside of the other class introduces tight coupling which is usually a bad idea anyway, and it forces you to use monkey patching, which is some additional headache you could avoid by slightly refactoring your class. I'm not saying monkey patching is bad, and perhaps moto is indeed something people would use in this case, but in general this is a typical case where there wouldn't be any problem if dependency injection had been used.

Comment: Tests that mock/patch stuff aren't the same code as in production either.

Comment: Dependency injection can be useful, but the way you've shown here is not how to do DI. In OP's code the `S3_Client()` *is* a client. In your code the `S3_Client()` has a client attribute, it's a client wrapped in a client now. Any code that used `client.fetch` would now need to use `client.client.fetch`. Modifying the code to use DI would mean a complete refactor of library code itself, passing in client explicitly to any function which needs one, it's not simply adding an optional argument into the client class.

Comment: OP's `S3_Client` is already a client wrapper, I didn't modify it apart from moving the responsibility to create the inner client outside the wrapper, so there's no `client.client.fetch`, it would work exactly the same. Perhaps this is not the smartest design but it works and achieves OP's objective without having to introduce additional packages/frameworks.

Comment: Hmm, yep, you are right about it already being a client wrapper - I just looked more closely and saw they've assigned the *actual* client to an attribute `S3_Client().s3` (very confusing!). But my point stands that this leaves the branch where `s3 is None` uncovered, which means it's not a useful approach for testing any library code which itself instantiates an `S3_Client` - that code would still need monkeypatching. So this approach will only work for testing the methods of `S3_Client` directly.